# How does the Linux kernel know how many bytes it should read from system call path arguments?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, parameter-passing, system-calls, abi

I searched in google I found that Linux kernel uses a struct for variables.

```
#define EMBEDDED_LEVELS 2
struct nameidata {
    struct path path;
    struct qstr last;
    struct path root;
    struct inode    *inode; /* path.dentry.d_inode */
    unsigned int    flags;
    unsigned    seq, m_seq;
    int     last_type;
    unsigned    depth;
    int     total_link_count;
    struct saved {
        struct path link;
        struct delayed_call done;
        const char *name;
        unsigned seq;
    } *stack, internal[EMBEDDED_LEVELS];
    struct filename *name;
    struct nameidata *saved;
    struct inode    *link_inode;
    unsigned    root_seq;
    int     dfd;
} __randomize_layout;
```

for example for `execve` systeml call (found here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c) 
this function will pass the filename pointer to another function as a **pathName** and set the **nameidata** struct name to this **pathName**

```
static int __do_execve_file(int fd, struct filename *filename,
                struct user_arg_ptr argv,
                struct user_arg_ptr envp,
                int flags, struct file *file)
```

my question here is how is it calculating the length of the parameter passed to this function from stack (for example `"/bin/sh"`)?

(Editor's note: the `const char *pathname` arg to [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) doesn't *have* to point to stack memory.  I think this question is assuming the shellcode use-case where you do construct a path on the user-space stack and pass a pointer to that.)

(I am learning assembly and I'm stuck in parameter passing section to system calls)

Comment: The pathName arg to `execve` points to a `0`-terminated / implicit-length C-string.  The kernel uses some kind of `strlen` on that user-space memory, just like if you passed it to `printf`.  Is that what you're asking?  You don't need to know the kernel internals to just *use* system calls like `execve` or `open` that take C strings by pointer.

Comment: Yes i know that i don't need to know the kernel internals. but i'm a discoverer and i won't get the hole idea if i miss something in my programming career.

Comment: and this is not just for shellcdoe use-case. actually it isn't. it was just about how parameter lenght would be calculated from the stack

Comment: What stack?  System call args are passed in registers.  Nothing implicitly uses the user-space stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux uses zero terminated strings, which are the standard string format for C.  The end of the string is marked by a zero byte, any bytes beyond the first zero byte in the string are not part of the string. Notably that this means that filenames cannot have a zero byte in them. (For the same reason most shellcode can't have a zero byte, as they're meant to exploit some sort of string buffer overflow.)

In practice the kernel often doesn't need to know the length of a filename, and uses functions like `strcmp` which compare strings byte by byte, stopping either at the first byte that compares different or at the first zero byte encountered.  If necessary however the length of a string can be computed with a function like `strlen`.

Comment: System-call args must get copied into kernel-owned memory, though, not accessed repeatedly from user-space.  Linux makes a big deal out of `copy_from_user` for accessing user-space memory and presumably only does that once.

Comment: strcmp and strlen would be easy exploits, I sure hope the kernel uses strncmp and strnlen instead.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure I suggested otherwise.  Note that Linux uses `strncpy_from_user` to copy strings from user space.

Comment: I was talking about your phrase *In practice the kernel often doesn't need to know the length of a filename*. That's true in general but this question is about how many byte the kernel reads from user-space for system-call inputs.  So `strncpy_from_user` is the specific answer, if I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @PeterCordes It reads the bytes until it finds the zero byte that marks the end.  It doesn't need to know the length of the string to do so. The name of the function used to copy the filename doesn't explain how the Linux kernel "knows how many bytes it should read", so `strncpy_from_user` is not in any way the answer.

Comment: Ok, I meant along with an explanation of what the ISO C function `strncpy` does, i.e. how implicit-length C strings work, which is already present in your answer.  So the most *specific* answer is that it copies bytes from user-space starting with the pointed-to byte from the pointer arg, up to and including a terminating `0`.  And that all of this is implemented by `strncpy_from_user` so if the OP wants to  look at more kernel code, that's the function name to look for.

Comment: So you mean if for example we set the ebx register(for filename argument for execve systemcall) ,It will start reading from that address until it reaches the null byte (0x90)??i thought we are setting 4 byte of the stack (int 32bit system) in ebx register.

Comment: @aidinjalalvandi It will read until it finds the first zero byte, which is 0x00.

Comment: @RossRidge Yes of course, I forgot the 0x90 is for nop, not null terminator. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my answer 
here is the source code that i found

```
#include <stdio.h>

char hello[] = "HelloA\0AAABB";

int main( void )
{
   __asm__
   (
    "mov $hello , %eax;"
    "push %eax;"
    "call myprint;"
   );
}

void myprint(char input[])
{
    printf("%s" , input);
}
```

I found that '\0' is the string terminator.so the above code will just output the "HelloA".The rest of it will be ignored.

Another interesting thing that i found is that when you create an array of char in C. the compiler will add a byte at the end of it for the null terminator.

So if we create something like this

```
char hello[] = "Hello"
```

It actually compile it like this :

```
char hello[] = "Hello\0"
```

and the size of your hello will be 6 instead of 5.
Finally in assembly programming we have to consider the null terminator for parameters passing in system calls. as long as the linux kernel has been written in C programming language we have to accept the rules of C programming language.

Here is the Gdb result of char hello[]

```
0x8049597 <hello>:      0x48    0x65    0x6c    0x6c    0x6f    0x41    0x00    0x41
0x804959f <hello+8>:    0x41    0x41    0x42    0x42    0x00    0x77    0x6f    0x72
```

The 0x8049597 is the start address of our string ("HelloA\0AAABB").
we put the \0 after A character. the character 'A' is equals to 0x41 hex number in Ascii table. and the \0 is 0x00.
That's why the printf function will just show 6 first characters of our string.

Comment: `printf` isn't a system call.  It's a libc function.  Also, your inline asm is broken; it modifies registers without using clobbers to tell the compiler what you're doing.  You even leave ESP modified because you forgot `add $4, %esp`.  You *could* have avoided destroying EAX with `push $hello`

Comment: @PeterCordes i never said that printf is a systemcall, i just found this code on the internet about inline assembly in c, and i modified the assembly to call a function.i used gcc 5.2 and it worked.

Comment: You posted this as an answer to a question about *system calls*.  Oh, there is a paragraph in there about  how this applies to the Linux kernel; I didn't see that because it's kind of buried in the middle of your examples.  Anyway, you *can* write code in C that handles strings in terms of pointer+ explicit length.  For example, the C++ `std::string` class is written in plain C++.  So is ISO C `fwrite`, and the kernel code that handles a `write(fd, buf, len)` system call.  It's just a matter of using `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`